# How to create scatter plot with 3 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a df which looks:

```
df_results = pd.DataFrame(data={})
df_results['names'] = ['James', 'Lucas', 'Henry', 'James', 'Lucas', 'Henry']
df_results['try_name'] = ["try_1", "try_1", "try_1", "try_2", "try_2", "try_2"]
df_results['score'] = [0.7, 0.9, 0.3, 0.91, 0.1, 0.2]

   names try_name  score
0  James    try_1   0.70
1  Lucas    try_1   0.90
2  Henry    try_1   0.30
3  James    try_2   0.91
4  Lucas    try_2   0.10
```

I want to create a plot (scatter) where:

- x axis is column `try_name`
- y axis is column `score`
- The values (point in the graph) are according to column `names` (3 different colors)

How can I create this plot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure matplotlib solution:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for name in df_results.names.unique():
    ax.scatter(df_results[df_results.names == name].try_name, 
               df_results[df_results.names == name].score, label=name)
ax.legend()
```

Using pandas plot:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for i,name in enumerate(df_results.names.unique()):
    df_results[df_results.names == name].plot.scatter('try_name', 'score', 
                                                      ax=ax, color='C{}'.format(i), 
                                                      label=name)
ax.legend()
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do it with pandas plot ?

Comment: Added a version using pandas plot, does it answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You could use seaborn's [**`swarmplot()`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html), [**`stripplot()`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html), or [**`scatterplot()`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html).

For example with [**`swarmplot()`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html):

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.swarmplot(data=df_results, x='try_name', y='score', hue='names')
```

[image: swarmplot example]

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do it with pandas plot ?